# "during cleaning the room" is grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar

I was told that "during cleaning the room" was not a correct expression.
I don't see why.
Could you explain the reason the expression is worng?
I am curious about the correct usage of "during"

One mentioned in a comment that "while cleaning the room" is a common expression.

Is it ok for me to understand that
"during + noun" is acceptable and "during + gerund" is not acceptable?

Comment: What context are you using it in?

Comment: I figure that the expression itself is wrong regardless of the context. That's what I was told.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "while cleaning the room" seems more idiomatic. There's no reason, it's just what people say.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: "During" does not license gerund-participial clauses as complement, but it does allow NPs. Thus, you can say "during [the cleaning of the room]".

Comment: Close? Really? Because you can’t explain why?

Comment: What @BillJ said. It should probably be *during **the** cleaning of **the** room*. Same as [***during the changing of the guard***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22during+the+changing+of+the+guard%22)

Answer (score 12):

There is a difference between a noun ending in *-ing* heading a noun phrase and a verb ending in *-ing* heading a gerund-participial clause. The noun phrase is allowed by *during* while the gerund-participial is not.

Since the example given includes an object (*the room*) in the phrase headed by *cleaning*, it is clearly a gerund-participial clause, and thus not allowed by *during*.

Searching the Corpus of Contemporary American English for the string

> . During *ing ,

produces 164 hits, while searching for

> . During *ing the

produces zero hits where *the...* is an object.

The former are nouns as they may be modified by adjectives, but not adverbs.

> During basic training,
>
> During recent testing,
>
> During major healing,
>
> etc.

Compare:

> During light cleaning...    [acceptable]
>
> During light cleaning the attic...  [unacceptable]
>
> While lightly cleaning the attic...  [acceptable]

Answer (score 1):

> During fumigation of the room
>
> While fumigating the room.

We don't say "during fumigating the room" because **during** wants a noun or noun-phrase complement whose action or existence occurs over time.

> during the game
>
> during interrogation of the suspect

And even though -ing forms can function as nominals, when you include a direct object and emphasize the time-aspect, as **during** does, it makes them act like verbs, and we use **while** with continuous verbs.

But what about a single word  like **sleeping**?  There's no direct object there. Can we say "during sleeping"? No, we say "while sleeping" or "during sleep". If you emphasize the time-aspect, the word acts like a verb.  So maybe all that is needed to turn the -ing form into a verb is to emphasize the time-aspect. At least when the verb is intransitive.

You could counteract this emphasis with transitives by using an article or adjective, as that pulls the word back into noun territory:

> During the fumigating, wear a mask.
>
> During extended fumigating, wear a diving suit.

Though those might sound  a tad off to a some percentage of speakers when there is a frequently used abstract noun available as is the case with **fumigation**.

You can also "convert" or "cast" the -ing form to a noun with an attribute, either before the word or as a complement that attaches the attribute back to the head noun:

> During *tank* cleaning, wear goggles.
>
> During cleaning *of the tank*, wear goggles.

Comment: Hello. Tim. DW256 has said all this, haven't they?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: No, not all this, and when I started typing it, it was early AM here and there were no answers yet; I just didn't save my answer right away.  And while I was out riding my bike, I thought of something else to add, which I will do in a moment.

Answer (score -3):

> [Oxford Learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gerund)
> Gerund: ​a noun in the form of the present participle of a verb (that is, ending in -ing)
> for example: *travelling* in the sentence *I preferred travelling alone.*

According to Google ngram, usage use of during+gerund has increased during the last century, particularly in the last half. Walking, running, eating and thinking all show this pattern. To take only one example of many, we have:

> [Teach me physiology](https://teachmephysiology.com/respiratory-system/ventilation/mechanics-of-breathing/)
> During breathing, the contraction and relaxation of muscles acts to change the volume of the thoracic cavity.

Such usage is concise, preferable to its long-winded avoidance such as “during the action of breathing”.

The idea that the usage is “wrong” may stem from prescriptive nineteenth century grammarians but has been overtaken by usage and conciseness. It is now neither helpful nor useful.

Comment: In "I preferred travelling alone", "travelling is a verb, not a noun. This example is called a catenative construction, where "prefer" is a catenative verb with the non-finite subordinate clause "travelling alone" as its catenative complement.

Comment: @BillJ please direct your criticism at the Oxford Learners site and niot at my reference to it.

Comment: @Anton It is fair, though, to level criticism at users who get grammar information from dictionaries. And especially if those dictionaries give completely topsy-turvy analyses which are confusing and misleading for learners,  it is essential that users explain why those analyses are wrong and muddleheaded under the posts that they appear in, and downvote them. Oxford dictionaries is misleading, self-contradictory  and wrong here.

Comment: How did your search on Google Ngram show that "during + gerund" has increased over the last century?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with ‘during breathing’, because _breathing_ **is a noun** there. ‘During lunch’ and ‘during eating’ are also both fine (though ‘while eating’ would be more common), but ‘*during eating lunch’ is ungrammatical. This has nothing to do with 19th-century prescriptivism, it’s just every bit as wrong as ‘*while lunch’ is.

Comment: Many native speakers would find **during breathing** ungrammatical, which is to say, no one they know would say it, and nothing they've read or would be likely to read would use that locution. These uses are marginal.

Comment: One of the problems with Google ngram is that it often counts the same attestation multiple times. The graphs are often the result of such artefacts.